# Como hacer una multiplicacion entre un DoubleVar y un int en python-Tkinter

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

No encuentro la forma de hacer la multiplicacion entre un DoubleVar() obtenido de un Entry, me arroja error (TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'DoubleVar' and 'float' )
Mi intencion es mostrar el 75% en el casillero "se lleva" del valor obtenido en "Propina mozo A".
Cree la funcion  getDato(), pero no puedo aplicarle la multiplicacion por 0.75
Ruego me puedan orientar en que estoy fallando.
Gracias!

```
from tkinter import *

ventana = Tk()

ventana.geometry('620x270')
ventana.title('DISTRITO | Reparto de Propinas')

# ENCABEZADO
encabezado = Label(ventana, text='Reparto Propinas')
encabezado.config(
    fg='white',
    bg='#6F232F',
    font=('Open Sans', 18),
    padx=220,
    pady=10
)
encabezado.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=4)

def getDato():
    resultado.set(propinaMozo1.get())
    

propinaMozo1 = DoubleVar()
resultado = DoubleVar() * 0.75


# MOZO A
# LABEL
propMozoA = Label(ventana, text='Propina de Mozo A: ')
propMozoA.grid(row=1, column=0, padx=5, pady=5)
# ENTRY
importeMozoA = Entry(ventana, textvariable=propinaMozo1)
importeMozoA.grid(row=1, column=1, sticky=W, padx=5, pady=5)
# LABEL
seLlevaMozoA = Label(ventana, text='Se lleva: ')
seLlevaMozoA.grid(row=1, column=2, padx=5, pady=5)
# ENTRY
importeParaMozoA = Entry(ventana, textvariable=resultado)
importeParaMozoA.grid(row=1, column=3, sticky=W, padx=5, pady=5)
importeParaMozoA.config(state='disabled')

Label(ventana).grid(row=4, column=1)
Label(ventana).grid(row=5, column=1)
Label(ventana).grid(row=6, column=1)

boton = Button(ventana, text='CALCULAR', padx=10, pady=10, command=getDato)
boton.grid(row=7, column=1)
boton.config(bg='#6F232F', fg='#ccc')


ventana.mainloop()
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, me salvaste.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tu problema esta principalmente con la variable `resultado` donde haces lo siguiente :

```
resultado = DoubleVar() * 0.75
```

Generado el error `(TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'DoubleVar' and 'float')`.

Donde te dice que hay un operador no soportado, que en este caso es `*`. Estas intentado multiplicar por 0.75 un DoubleVar(), esta operación no esta permitida.

Se que lo que intentabas es que al dar un valor a `resultado`, este se multiplique directamente y luego con la función `getDato()` retornar directamente el valor multiplicado.

`Pero DoubleVar() es un tipo de variable`. No puedes realizar este tipo de operaciones aritméticas en la declaración de la variable. (Tampoco es permitido sumar, restar, dividir....)

---

Por lo que tu código debería de presentar los siguientes cambios :

Primero, indicas que la variable `resultado` es una variable de tipo `DoubleVar()` sin realizar ningún tipo de operaciones de calculo.

```
resultado = DoubleVar()
```

Seguido de esto debes modificar tu función `getDato()` indicando ahí la operación que quieres realizar :

```
def getDato():
    resultado.set(propinaMozo1.get() * 0.75)
```

Comment: Cualquier tipo de duda o aclaración que necesites escribe un comentario!